# Как обновить данные в ListView, и стать в конец списка

Tags: c#, xamarin

Здравствуйте. Перечитал много всего, но так и не понял, как мне обновить данные в ListView. У меня чат. Я с одного компьютера посылаю на другой сообщение. Так вот, нужно это сообщение отобразить, став в конец списка. Подскажите как это сделать? Использую команду:

((BaseAdapter)ListView1.Adapter).NotifyDataSetChanged();

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Обновление данных:

```
            List<WebAPI.TMessage> sMess = new List<WebAPI.TMessage>();
            sMess = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WebAPI.TMessage>>(stream.ReadToEnd());

            bool isChange = false;
            foreach (var item in sMess)
            {
                i = Math.Max(i, item.Id);
                list.AddRange(new string[] { item.Id.ToString() + ":" + item.sUser + ":" + item.sMessage + ":" + item.dtTime.ToString() });
                isChange = true;
            }
            if (isChange)
            {
                    ((BaseAdapter)ListView1.Adapter).NotifyDataSetChanged();

                    // прокручиваем до конца
                    ListView1.SmoothScrollToPosition(list.Count);
                }
```

Адаптер (часть кода):

```
    private List<string> list;

    private Context context;

    public LanguageAdapter(Context context, List<string> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // используем созданные, но не используемые view
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Messanger.Resource.Layout.PosMassege, parent, false);
        }

        string p = list[position];

        ((TextView)view.FindViewById<TextView>(Messanger.Resource.Id.textView1)).Text =p;
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте ObservableCollection вместо List в качестве источника коллекции
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Это первое, что нужно сделать, чтобы View отслуживало изменения в источнике.